# Loading multiple images in Matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, loading, matlab-guide

I want to load multiple images in Matlab GUI.
Algorithm below:

```
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
[filename path] = uigetfile('*.jpg','*.png','Chose files to 
load','MultiSelect','on');

if isequal(filename,0) || isequal(path,0) 
return
end


if iscell(filename)
img = cell(size(filename));
for ii = 1:numel(filename)
  img{ii} = imread(fullfile(path,filename{ii}));
end
else
img{1} = imread(fullfile(path,filename));
end


filename = strcat(path,filename);
fullpathname = strcat(path, filename);
set(handles.edit1,'String', fullpathname);
fileID = fopen(strcat(path, filename), 'r');
```

It works in case of loading one image, but in case of loading multiple images, it gives mi subsequent error:

```
Error using imread>parse_inputs (line 457)
The file name or URL argument must be a string.

Error in imread (line 316)
[filename, fmt_s, extraArgs] = parse_inputs(varargin{:});

Error in untitled>pushbutton1_Callback (line 112)
im = rgb2gray(imread(filename));

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 95)
    feval(varargin{:});

Error in untitled (line 42)
gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in 
@(hObject,eventdata)
untitled('pushbutton1_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))
```

Could you please give me a hint, so I could make it functional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`uigetfile` returns in `filename`:

> a character vector or a cell array of character vectors.

(From the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uigetfile.html#d120e1281290)). The former happens when selecting one file, the latter when selecting multiple files.

Thus, if you want to be ale to select multiple files, your code needs to handle that case by checking to see if `iscell(filename)`, and if so, looping over each of its elements.

Also, please use `fullfile` to concatenate parts of a path or file name, it will prevent portability issues down the road.

---

You could write code like this:

```
[filename,path] = uigetfile({'*.jpg';'*.png'},'Chose files to load','MultiSelect','on');

if isequal(filename,0)
   return
end

if iscell(filename)
   img = cell(size(filename));
   for ii = 1:numel(filename)
      img{ii} = imread(fullfile(path,filename{ii}));
   end
else
   img{1} = imread(fullfile(path,filename));
end
```

Now `img` is a cell array containing all the images selected.

Comment: I want to be able choose either one image or multiple images.
What should I change in the algorithm?

Comment: Please see the edit of the original question. 
I also need to be able to see the directory either of an image or images. It gives me the error in edited question.

I am sorry I didn't mention it sooner.

Comment: @Franta: Please don't change the question after receiving an answer, as it invalidates the answer. You can add to it if the answer doesn't fully address the question, or you can ask a new question if it is a different question (even if it is related). I have rolled back your edit.

Comment: @Franta: Anyway, it seems to me you don't fully understand the answer. You are now getting an error in the second part, where again you concatenate `path` and `filename`. This is the same issue. If `filename` is a cell array, this concatenation produces something different. Please use the debugger and step through your code line by line, examining the value of the variables and seeing what value `fullpathname` gets after concatenating a string with a cell array of strings.

Comment: @Brice: `size` returns a vector of sizes, not a scalar. `img` will have the same size as `filename`.